# Fortran/OpenMP - Does parallel do suffer from race condition?

Tags: fortran, openmp, race-condition

I always thought `parallel do` in OpenMP (I use Fortran) does not suffer from race conditions. I just needed confirmation on the same.

So I wrote this simple program to test it

```
program test
 use omp_lib
 implicit none
integer, parameter :: m = 4
real*8, dimension(m,m) :: b
integer :: i, j
b = 1.0
!$ call omp_set_num_threads(4)
    !$omp parallel do
    do i = 1, m
        do j = 1, m
            b(i,j) = 2*b(i,j)
            if(i==j) then
                b(i,j) = b(i,j) + i
            endif
        end do
    end do
    !$omp end parallel do

print *, b
end program test
```

This program gives the result I expected (i.e. no race condition detected).

But I fear that something might be escaping from my simple mind. Can anyone confirm that `parallel do` does not suffer from race condition or otherwise?

Comment: Please elaborate, why and where do you think there should be a race condition?

Comment: @HristoIliev : I'm new to openMP. The matrix update b(i,j) is the place where I expect a race condition, if at all it exists. Since for each loop (given i and j), the element b of b(i,j) is unique and hence the race condition is avoided. Is this right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. No two threads access the same matrix element, therefore no race condition is present.

Comment: The example does appear to pose false sharing, which may defeat the purpose of parallelization (even if the example is made large enough to motivate the attempt).  Certain compilers may correct the loop nesting when OpenMP is not enabled, but observe the nesting literally when compiling with OpenMP.

Comment: @tim18 : Can you explain what do you mean by false sharing?

Comment: You are iterating your array in wrong order. The outermost loop should be j and innermost i for good performance. It is tje opposite as in C and C++. See column major order.

Comment: @SaravanaKumar, false sharing occurs when two threads running on different cores access distinct memory locations that happen to reside in the same cache line. If one thread writes to one such location, the cache line is invalidated in all other cores that hold the same cache line. This could happen in your example with `b(i,j)` and `b(i+1,j)` (stored consecutively in memory in Fortran) for values of `i` that are multiples of the chunk size of the parallel loop when that chunk size is not a multiple of the number of doubles that fit in a cache line (8 doubles on x86).

Comment: @HristoIliev:Thanks! I'm learning a lot here.